# How to write the equation of this graph?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

[image]

How can we write the equation of this graph. I know that the general equation of an exponential graph is $y(t) = AB^{Lt} + C$ . the equation of the graph in the figure does not look exponential but its Equation is written as $y(t)=Ae^{-Lt}+Be^{​−Mt} + C$.(NOTE all bold letters are Constants) Can any body explain please that how to write the Equation of this graph as the sum of exponential terms as it is shown in the equation $y(t)=Ae^{-Lt}+Be^{​−Mt} + C$?
​​

Comment: yes i asked this question before but now in a better way. i am sorry. will anyone help please. i have more explained my question.

Comment: i can write the equation of the exponential curve from the graph but i really dont understand how one can write the equation as the sum of exponential function from the graph and which type of graph gives us the equation of the curve as the sum of two functions @JessicaK

Comment: It looks a bit like a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) to me...

Comment: Can you please make sure you close all parathesis you opened? And please [use LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you have the equatino $y(t) = Ae^{-Lt}+Be^{-Mt}+C$
Since $y(0) = 1$ we know that $$1 =  Ae^{0}+Be^{0} +c= A+B+C.$$

Further we have $\lim_{x\to \infty} y(t) = 0$ which suggests that $L>0$, $M>0$ and $C = 0$ therefore $B = 1-A$. All we have to do now is considering the equation

$$y(t) = Ae^{-Lt}+(1-A)e^{-Mt}$$

In order to get an ascending and then again descending curve, we need one of the one of the sigs of $B$ and $A$ positive and the other one negative. Lets say we want $B>0$ , then $A<1$. In order to have that prominent maximum we need the growth rates to be different.

So setting $A = -11$, $M=2$ and $L = 3$ results in a very similar curve.

You can estimate $A,M$ and $L$ using any regression technique, IF you know some points of the curve.

Comment: thanks for the answer @flawr . my question is actually how to write the equation of this graph ?

Comment: Thats what I just showed you, what parts are unclear to you?

Comment: I think you mean $y(0) = 1$.

Comment: @JessicaK Of course, thank you for noticing! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: well , i have come to know that such a graph is known as the double exponential graph . and its equation is y=ae^bx
+ce^dx + k. do you know about this ? @JessicaK . i think if we are able to identify the double exponential graph then this equation will be the equation of the double exponential graph.

Answer (score 0):

It is a guessing game.
The curve may be  of type 
$$y = A e^ {-B t} + C\;t $$
which consists of an increasing part and a decreasing part in additive mode, or, could be  of type

$$y = C  + A e^ {-B t} \; t $$

consisting of an increasing  and decreasing part in a product mode.

Apart from the value at $t=0$, you need to supply two more $x_i,y_i$ to find the constants numerically.

I suspect an inflection point $ (1,1). \frac {d^2y}{dx^2} =0  $ here.

Comment: ok sir thank you but can you tell me the name of this function ?

Comment: As one such shape the curve in                                                            http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law                         can be made to begin at its first inflection point.